# Initializing method defined in model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, initialization

I've  got a method in my generator model:

```
def generate_pesel
    r1 = Random.new
    rok = r1.rand(1800...2299)
    r2 = Random.new
    miesiac = r2.rand(1...12)
    r3 = Random.new

    if (miesiac == 2)&&((rok%4==0)||(rok%400))
      dzien = r3.rand(1...29)
    else
      dzien = r3.rand(1...28)
    end

    if (rok >= 1800)&&(rok <= 1899)
      miesiac = miesiac + 80
    end 
    if (rok >= 2000)&&(rok <= 2099)
      miesiac = miesiac + 20
    end
    if (rok >= 2100)&&(rok <= 2199)
      miesiac = miesiac + 40
    end
    if (rok >= 2200)&&(rok <= 2299)
      miesiac = miesiac + 60
    end

    data = rok.to_s + miesiac.to_s + dzien.to_s
    puts data
  end
```

And I want it to put data variable in my view - but I don't know how initialize it in my view - I've tried:

```
<%= generate_pesel %>
```

But it doesn't work (NoMethodError) :/
How initialize it? Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** directly reference models in your views.

Instead, create a variable in your controller

```
def show
  @generator = Generator.new # or create it however you like
  @data = @generator.generate_pesel
end
```

Then you can reference it in view

```
<%= @data %>
```

Comment: I've done it, but I've got an error: "undefined method `generate_pesel' for nil:NilClass" :/

Comment: Did you instantiate your `@generator`?

Comment: yes, but I did it in 'new' method, and I want to show @data in 'show' method - should I instantiate it again?

Comment: Yes, that's a completely separate method. You should instantiate again.

Comment: When I initialized it(@generator = Generator.new), I've got an error: "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in GeneratorsController#show "

Comment: Maybe there's some hidden problem with your model. But this is out of scope of this question. Post as new question.